# Splitting of the Moon By Prophet Muhammad (PBUH)

Tags: prophet-muhammad, history, moon

I have read about the incident wherein Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) split the moon in 2 and joined them back for the people to witness.

I have heard a folklore that a king in the Indian Subcontinent witnessed this and found our through his sources that it was done by Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) and set out for the Middle East leaving his kingdom however he passed away in his way and was buried somewhere in his path. Is there any truth to this folklore?

Comment: We can only answer questions on Islam, not on Indian folklore. This is off-topic.

Comment: @UmH Okk Is there a SE appropriate for this question?

Comment: HistorySE, ScepticismSE, … there are many possible fits?

Comment: @Medi1Saif so can you transfer it there?

Comment: If we find a good fit why not? You are free to suggest as I'm busy and not familiar with some of these sites.

Comment: @Medi1Saif I also wanted to ask that I've always been curious as a child. I am a practicing Muslim however people tell me I should refrain from asking such questions. Is it bad if I ask questions relating to incidents mentioned in the Qur'an?

Comment: @Medi1Saif I think History SE would be good as the question isn't very much related to scepticism rather to the tales surrounding the incident

Comment: Hm... my experience with historySE tells me that as is the question will be closed at once. You can ask anything I can't promise that you'll always get an answer.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Ok let's try for once if it's closed then so be it. I'll repost in some other SE which I find to be appropriate after some searching